# Okay to add new oil to old?

Tags: engine, oil, oil-change, lubrication

Title pretty much explains,

I change my oil every 4-6k miles depending on how generous I’m feeling, however will the oil dirty oil that’s already in the sump mix with the clean oil when topping up?

Normally I just top up but in this case I have had to drain about half a litre out on two occasions

First when I changed the oil as I overfilled

Second when topping up (overfilled again after 3k miles)

so it's had quite a bit of new oil mixed with the original stuff, just wondering will the new stuff mix fine with the old, if not I’m going do an early change and try not to be such a dope when topping up.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you change the oil, do you remove the sump plug and let as much drain out as possible, before you put the new in?

Comment: yeah, every 4-6k miles it's a complete drain and new filter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mixing new with the old will cause you absolutely no issues. As long as you are using the same weight oil, it will mix up and you'd never know it. Continue to change your oil at the specified interval and you should be golden.

Comment: The manufacturers interval states every 12k miles =/ that seams way too long to me so I went with a compromise on every 6k.

Comment: @ceefax12 - The 12k miles is their recommendation ... there is nothing saying you cannot do it sooner than that. This action does not void the warranty or anything, so good on yah.

Comment: I was too worried about this But, the maintenance light/engine oil is still showing. What to do?

Comment: @MasudRahman - It seems you have a separate issue. Please feel free to ask this as a question so it will get some deserved attention! [Click here](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to start a new question.

Comment: @ceefax12 What YMM? I would be very surprised to learn of a 12k Mile Severe-duty Interval. Is it a Diesel?

Answer (score 3):

Usually when changing the oil you won't be able to fully drain the old oil anyways and the old and new oils will mix, like it or not. Usually this is not a problem even if the weights are different, though it's safer to stick with the same brand, as some argue the components in the oil being incompatible may cause issues.

What you should be wary of is mixing synthetic oil with mineral oil, it i said that this causes problems more often.

Comment: I have heard it said about not mixing synthetic and mineral oil and never looked into whether it is true.  Isn't that what semi-synthetic oil is?  Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: @HandyHowie As far as I know it's exactly that - mineral oil with some part synthetic oil. Might be an urban legend, but compatibility issues between natural and synthetic oils are said to be more pronounced. When semi-synthetic blends are made the manufacturer probably knows what to mix and what not to mix. Probably won't kill the engine and it's better to add some mineral oil than to drive low on synthetic, but this could reduce destabilize the oil and reduce it's performance.

Comment: I personally think it's not that much of a big deal, mixing brands is alright and mixing synthetic with mineral is alright only if there is no other option.

Comment: @HandyHowie is spot on. There is no issue with mixing Dino oil and synthetic, as that's what the "blend" oils are all about. There are no compatibility issues with doing so. This will not cause more sludge or have a chemical reaction of some sort.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 any references? It's a very controversial subject, so I would rather err on the safe side.

Comment: You can read the [Mobil1 page on semi-synthetic oils](https://mobiloil.com/en/article/car-maintenance/learn-about-motor-oil-facts/types-of-synthetic-oil). It describes *exactly* what a semi-synthetic blend is, which is what you are describing by mixing Dino and synthetic. And you are right, it's a *very* controversial subject. [I had this concern a while ago](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/261/4152).

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the blends are clear, but what about mixing finished different type oil products into the engine? Where did this fear come from?

Comment: For example here Penrite does not recommend doing this intentionally as this might degrade oil performance: http://www.penriteoil.com.au/faq.php

Comment: [Read this article](http://www.carbibles.com/engineoil_bible.html). I find it to be very neutral, talking about oil itself and not lending to the hype. There is a section on mixing oil types. It states, "*There is no scientific data to support the idea that mixing mineral and synthetic oils will damage an engine.*" In the article, it states "*pure synthetics do not mix with mineral oil*", which is true, but pure synthetics are not used in any motor oil, which is explained. Mineral and synthetics are compatible.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 will do, it's a long one. I agree that engine damage is improbable, I wonder how it affects oil performance. I noticed most of the articles talk about mixing the oils when completely changing one type of oil for another, which is apparently alright most of the times. Rarely they mention adding one type oil to the engine when another is used, which is what is being discussed in this question.,

Answer (score 1):

Mixing old with new won't hurt anything. If your engine is consuming too much oil, for instance, you would need to add new oil more frequently because you need the right oil level all the time. I have got cars that needed as much as 1L of new oil every 1 or 2 weeks because the oil piston rings where kaput. Nothing happened except $ going down there as frequently as not eager to :)